# Heroku Devise Mailer: says mailgun credentials invalid but mailgun isn't part of my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I'm having trouble in production on Heroku, with Devise confirmable email.  I'd been using Mailgun for this and am migrating to Mandrill.  All references to Mailgun have been removed from the code, so a search for "mailgun" comes up empty, including my vendor folder.  My new setup is for Mandrill SMTP.  When I test signing up a user on Heroku my output includes this:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 5.7.0 Mailgun is not loving your login or password 
 vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:969:in    `check_auth_response' 
vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:740:in `auth_plain' 
vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:732:in `authenticate' 
vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:567:in `do_start' 
vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'  
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
```

I've removed my Heroku ENV variables, removed the Mailgun addon but it seems like there's a setting which is not part of my code that needs to be updated to resolve this. Why is it stuck on Mailgun?

Answer (score 3):

I am an idiot.  I had an ENV variable for SMTP_ADDRESS which I was using for both applications.  It was still set to Mailgun's url.